# com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to my custom class

Tags: kotlin, gson

I am getting:

```
com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to Message class
```

I want to convert a any type object to my custom class. I am trying gson to convert the object to JSON and then JSON string to my `Message` class.

I created a function with generic type conversion with Gson.

```
//Custom Class
data class Message(
    @SerializedName("content")
    val content: String? = null
)

//My abstract class

abstract class EchoListener<T> {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = EchoListener::class.java.simpleName
    }

    abstract fun onDataReceived(data: T?)

    fun submitData(it: Any) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Echio data  ${it}")
        val gson = Gson()
        val json = gson.toJson(it)
        val data: EchoData<T> = gson.fromJson(json, genericType<EchoData<T>>())
        Log.e(TAG, "Converted data ${data.data}")
        onDataReceived(data.data)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> genericType() = object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type


class SomeClass {
    fun <T> listen(event: String, callback: EchoListener<T>) {
        val listener = Emitter.Listener {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data ${it[1]}")
            if (it.size > 1)
                callback.submitData(it[1])
        }
        this.socket.on(event, listener)
        this.bind(event, listener)
    }
}


//Main Activity
someClassObj?.listen("chat", object : EchoListener<Message>() {
    override fun onDataReceived(data: Message?) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message ${data}")
    }
})
```

**Edited**

**Here is the link to the library that I am creating:**
[Github repo](https://github.com/darkmat13r/android-echo)

**Here is the sample android application**
[Android Github Repo](https://github.com/darkmat13r/LaravelEchoChatAndroid)

Comment: I wrote something like what are you asking for, but using https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization (a serialization library by Kotlin team) not gson to convert it to JSON, does that help you? In other words, is the solution that you're searching for must be using gson?

Comment: @Abed thank you. Does it work for generic types?

Comment: Sure thing it works very well, I'm going to post the answer using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) in a fairly simple way. First, see an [exmple](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) to have an idea of how it works, then add the library dependency to the app build.gradle:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.13.0"
```

Note, to be able to use Kotlin serialization library in your Kotlin code, make sure that your Kotlin compiler version is `1.3.30` or higher.

Now you need to annotate all the classes that you want to serialize/deserialize with `@Serializable` annotation and make sure you are importing from `kotlinx.serialization.Serializable`.

After you annotate your classes the compiler will auto-generate a static function in the Java byte code called `serializer()` for each class, we will be calling this function to serialize and deserialize an object of that class.

Now to implement a generic serialize/deserialize function, add this file to your project:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.DeserializationStrategy
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.SerializationStrategy
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

object SerializationManager {

    fun <T> deserializeObject(
        json: String,
        deserializationStrategy: DeserializationStrategy<T>
    ): T = Json.parse(deserializationStrategy, json)


    fun <T> getList(json: String, dataSerializer: KSerializer<List<T>>): List<T> =
        Json.parse(dataSerializer, json)



    fun <T> serializeObject(data: T, serializationStrategy: SerializationStrategy<T>): String =
        Json.stringify(serializationStrategy, data)


    fun <T> serializeList(
        data: List<T>,
        dataSerializer: KSerializer<List<T>>
    ): String = Json.stringify(dataSerializer, data)

}
```

**An example of how to use SerializationManager**

I have a `Reciter` class that I want to serialize:

```
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

@Serializable
data class Reciter(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val servers: String
)
```

then in your `Activity` or elsewhere:

```
 val reciter = Reciter("A123", "ABCD", "https://stackoverflow.com")
 val json1 = SerializationManager.serializeObject(reciter, Reciter.serializer())


 // If we want to serialize a list of reciters, then we pass Reciter.serializer().list
 val recitersList = listOf(
     Reciter("A123", "ABCD", "https://stackoverflow.com"),
     Reciter("B456", "F.abc", "https://stackoverflow.com"),
     Reciter("M568", "NDK", "https://stackoverflow.com")
 )
 val json2 = SerializationManager.serializeList(recitersList,Reciter.serializer().list)
```

Comment: If you still have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: This will not solve the problem... Serialization and deserialization is not a problem with simple scenario and when the library knows the data type it is going to receive. The library doesn't know the type of the data to convert. The data type is provided by the user. Please check the github link provided.

Comment: Please check the android sample repo

Answer (score 2):

You try to use it in very complex way. It can be so much easier with [`Gson`](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide).

Here is four extension methods that will cover almost all of the cases you need. If no - I hope the rest you will figure out based on these.

```
inline fun <reified T> T.toJson(): String = Gson().toJson(this)

inline fun <reified T> String.toObject(): T = Gson().fromJson(this, T::class.java)

inline fun <reified T, K, V> Map<K, V>.toObject(): T = Gson().fromJson(this.toJson(), T::class.java)

// and more classic but less used
fun <T> String.toObject(type: Type): T = Gson().fromJson(this, type)
```

Now you can use it like

```
data class SomeClass(val today: Int, val yesterday: Int)

val someClass = SomeClass(3,4)
val json = someClass.toJson() // { "today" : 3,"yesterday" : 4 }
val someClassDesetialized = json.toObject<SomeClass>() // SomeClass(3,4)

val map: Map<String, Int> = mapOf("today" to 2,"yesterday" to 1)
val mapJson= map.toJson() // { "today" : 2,"yesterday" : 1 }
val someClassFromMap = map.toObject<SomeClass, String, Int>() // SomeClass(2,1)
val someClassFromMapJson: SomeClass = mapJson.toObject<SomeClass>().copy(5) // SomeClass(5,1)

...

val data: EchoData<T> = json.toObject()
val data1 = json.toObject<EchoData<T>>()
```

Something like that. Note that Gson lib uses Java [serialization](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/) so it maybe slower and less secure than Kotlin specific [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) but it is not in prealpha version as kotlinx.serialization so it is less bug prone and more mature.

### Edit1

here is how to hide the conversion in quite the industry standard way.

```
inline fun <reified T> Map<String, Any>.convert(): T = toObject()
```

and then use it like

```
map.convert<SomeClass>()
```

it it better than pass the Type as method argument.

You will have to adjust this methods to be usable from the Java code though. [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html) it is explained how to do it.

### Edit2

Here is an architectural issue your app was having fixed

SomeClass from your example should be

```
class SomeClass {
        inline fun <reified T> listen(event: String, callback: (T) -> Unit) {
            Emitter.Listener {
                Log.e(TAG, "Data ${it[1]}")
                if (it.size > 1)
// I don't know what it[1] is so I assume it is map<String, Any> since it was in an original issue.
                    callback((it[1] as Map<String, Any>).toObject<T, String, Any>())
            }.apply{
                this@SomeClass.socket.on(event, this)
                this@SomeClass.bind(event, this)
            }
        }
    }
```

when its usage now can be reduced to

```
 SomeClass().listen<Message>("someEvent", { message ->
// do some stuff with message
            })
```

This is not the fix to an original conversion issue from Map to Pojo. This is an architectural fix of the flawed methods.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you right kotlin serialization library is still experimental, but that is not because of API is not stable yet, but that's because of the backward compatibility with kotlin "While library is stable and has successfully been used in various scenarios, there is no API compatibility guarantees between versions, that's why it is called experimental."

Comment: I'm confused. In one sentence you've said that the API is stable and unstable at the same time. Maybe you'd meant that the algorithms are stable but the API is not?  And if the situation will be as with coroutines - I would not recommend to use it in production. I had a bit of a headake moving coroutines from early release to production one. It is just not the optimal choice at the moment, in my opinion.

Comment: Not working. Same error  com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to **.samplechatdemo.data.Message

Comment: @AvinashKumawat just checked. I fixed usage of my methods - I was doing them in here so there were errors. Use the one for the ```map``` - ```map.toObject<SomeClass, String, Int>()```  where ```SomeClass``` is the class you want to convert your data to, ```String``` is the class of the map key and ```Int``` is the class of the map value. Class of the key and class of the value can be ```Any```. I just checked  - it is working correctly with ```LinkedTreeMap```. Retest please with fixed examples.

Comment: Yes it will work if i use this method in my activity class I don’t want to expose the conversion. The conversion should be done at the library side. User will have to pass the Data type.. like retrofit do with gson builder.. we just tell the api call interface method that the json we are receiving should be type of some Data type

Comment: @AvinashKumawat. I just edited the answer - you may check how the parsing could be hidden. You won't be able to hide the parsing more because you need to pass at least one parameter so the function knew what to parse. It is just like in retrofit - only the generic parameter is passed. It is better than actual Type as function argument.

Comment: The actual data type is send through activity
`someClassObj?.listen("chat", object : EchoListener<Message>() {})`

Comment: @AvinashKumawat this is completely different question already. I have answered correctly to you initial question - LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to my custom class - I have provided you with the method to transform your map to object. Now you are asking about architectural decisions made in your library - it should be done in other question. Mark this question as resolved, create new one and I will try to answer it in the best possible manner, because it is how it should be done.

Comment: Sorry brother... but the issue is not resolved. The problem is due to the type assurance not with the conversion. My code conversion was working if i didn't convert the data at the library and convert the data at my activity... You just made the extensions of the conversion. It is doing the same thing as I did. It doesn't make any change.it is Just simpler code and clean code nothing else.

Comment: @AvinashKumawat look at my Edit2 - I have fixed the second architectural issue you were having with passing the right generic parameter to the callback.